# What is Battler saying in Japanese whenever e asks a witch to repeat something (in red)?

Tags: japanese-language, umineko-when-they-cry

It sounds like 'shoyukyu'. For example, here, in episode 18 of the anime (part of the 3rd arc of the anime, which corresponds to the 3rd episode of the VN [Banquet of the Golden Witch](https://07th-expansion.fandom.com/wiki/Banquet_of_the_Golden_Witch)), Battler (or anyone on the human side eg Erika Furudo, Ange Ushiromiya, etc) asks a witch to repeat something.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/umineko/comments/t657hg/what_are_the_characters_saying_in_japanese_when/):

> 復唱 要求（ふくしょうようきゅう）

Rōmaji is: Fukushō yōkyū