# What do witches say when they refuse a repetition request (復唱 要求)?

Tags: japanese-language, umineko-when-they-cry

For example Episode 18, Eva-Beatrice refuses a [repetition request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66585/what-is-battler-saying-in-japanese-whenever-e-asks-a-witch-to-repeat-something) by saying 'I refuse!' Sounds like 'kyohi suru wa'.

[image]

In episode 9, Beatrice says 'I refuse.' Sounds like 'kyohi suru'.

[image]

In episode 14, Beatrice says more elaborately 'I refuse to repeat it.' Sounds like '復唱 kyohi suru' (Fukushō o kyohi suru).

[image]

1. What exactly are they saying?
2. Are they actually removing the personal pronoun 'I' (eg watashi or whatever) and so are just saying just 'Refuse' or 'Refuse to repeat' ?

Comment: Just a tip, you can try [an online dictionary](https://jisho.org/search/kyohi) first. Note that there's also [a minimum threshold for Japanese language questions to be accepted on Anime.SE](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/2516). Not just asking random Japanese phrase that appears on anime/manga.

Comment: @AkiTanaka ? https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66585/what-is-battler-saying-in-japanese-whenever-e-asks-a-witch-to-repeat-something

Comment: To be honest, that question was also kind of problematic.

Comment: This is a purely language question but this is also the type of question that Japanese.se does not like. So I'm just going to close it without migrating.

Comment: @кяαzєя ? https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66585/what-is-battler-saying-in-japanese-whenever-e-asks-a-witch-to-repeat-something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NipoJu](https://www.reddit.com/user/NipoJu/)'s answer in [umineko subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/umineko/comments/t657hg/comment/i78yj6u/?context=3):

> Yes, they say 拒否する, which literaly means "Refuse".
>
> In Japanese pronouns are not needed, and everything is understood by
> context. So if the witches say 拒否する right after asking for repetition
> in red, it really means: I refuse (to do so).
>
> The わ(wa) that Eva says is just a particle to make a sentence more
> ""feminine"", it depends on the person/characters personality. I can
> personally also see Bernkastel and Lambdadelta using the わ(wa) at the
> end, however I don't see Beatrice saying it since she has a more
> ""masculine""-ish way of talking.
>
> (I put quotes on feminine and masculine because it's a little
> old-fashion way of seeing it. I, as a man, use わ(wa) and don't really
> care if people see it as feminine)

Answer (score -1):

1. I believe it's

A - Episode 18 - (Not sure) 拒否するわ (きょひするわ。 Kyohi suru wa.)

B - Episode 9 - (Not sure) 拒否する (きょひする。 kyohi suru.)

C - Episode 14 - (I believe [I have a source](http://mooncryed.blog105.fc2.com/blog-entry-411.html).) 復唱を拒否する。

2. Looks like because whenever I type in 'I' in google translate, it gives watashi.

For example '私はそれを復唱ことを拒否します' translates to 'I refuse to repeat it.'